# Publishing xunit test results in Azure Devops fails with "No Result Found to Publish"

Tags: azure-pipelines, xunit

I want to publish xunit test results in an Azure Devops release pipeline using the "Publish test results" task Version 1.* and 2.*.

Although xunit test file is present and has content - I checked with `ls` and `cat` commands in the pipepline I get an error message like this:

```
2020-02-13T08:23:10.9093662Z Obtained XUnit Test Run Start Date: 2020-02-13T08:23:10.9092530Z and Completed Date: 2020-02-13T08:23:10.9092530Z
2020-02-13T08:23:10.9144214Z No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/report/report.xml'.
2020-02-13T08:23:10.9149123Z Obtained XUnit Test Run Start Date: 2020-02-13T08:23:10.9148260Z and Completed Date: 2020-02-13T08:23:10.9148260Z
2020-02-13T08:23:10.9149993Z No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/report/report1.xml'.
```

The two files `report1.xml` and `report2.xml` get discovered properly but Azure DevOps says `No Result Found to Publish`and hesitates to publish them.

Comment: Hi, which test task do you use to run the xunit test? Since this task supports xunit v2 not v1, please check which version of xunit do you use.

Comment: I tried both variants. No difference.

Comment: There's also this issue which suggests a possible issue and fix, although it did not work for me:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12772

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround to the problem which does not really solve the xunit publish issue but I can live with that.

The Xunit test result I would like to publish is from a testcafe runner which has many reporting possibilities. I switched to [testcafe-reporter-junit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-junit) and exported a junit test report. Then using the test publisher for junit files and everything works.

Since switching to VSTest also resolved it maybe it is just the xunit test publisher which has an issue.

Comment: I had the same issue, but got it working by using JUnit in Azure DevOps task and XUnit in robot framework output format.

Comment: I tried the other fixes with VSTest (see above) but those made no difference. 

This fixed it. (a) switch to JUnit reporter; (b) set extension to xml, (c) pipeline testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'. 

Job done.

Comment: My xunit.xml was generated by the Robot Framework and simply switching the 'Test result format' to JUnit in the Publish Test Results task worked for me too.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using `dotnet test` task in this way:

[image]

You may need to set `VSTest` instead of `Xunit` in Publish Test Result Task:

[image]

I met same message like yours and then resolve it by changing `Xunit` to `VSTest`. I think you may encounter similar issue.

**In addition:**

And as I know, built-in tasks such as `Visual Studio Test task` and `Dot NetCore CLI task` **automatically** publish test results to the pipeline, so you actually don't need a **separate** `Publish Test Results task` in the pipeline. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more details.

E.g： Dotnet test task by default will generate and publish test results:

[image]

Hope it makes some help :)

Comment: Should be marked as answer.